# Moving a question should be a top-level option when flagging, and contain an "Other" option

Tags: feature-request, flags, migration

I'd like to propose a new feature: that there should be a top-level option when flagging, and an "other" option in the Flag -> Migration dialog.

For example, I'd like to move [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33748072/with-modern-fillrates-and-deferred-rendering-is-occlussion-culling-still-releva) to Computer Graphics, but not only did I have to google to even learn how to flag my question for moving, it even turns out that the selection is limited, and doesn't even contain an "Other" option!

Answer (score 3):

There is an option.

Stack Exchange Sites only have the option for users to migrate to 5 sites. This excludes beta sites. Since Computer Graphics SE is currently in beta, no Stack Exchange site has the ability to migrate a question to, or from Computer Graphics, *without the assistance of a moderator*.

If you would like a question to be moved, use a custom moderator flag and explain where you would like to migrate your question, *and why*. Provide an argument. Simply saying "migrate please" will probably just waste the moderator's time and result in a declined flag.

---

Alternatively, since you've realized you may have a better question on another Stack Exchange site, delete your question on the first site, and then re-ask the question on Computer Graphics. This is something that you can do: Just make sure the question is on-topic, and you're set. I generally encourage this: If a user can realize that a question is on-topic on other site, and that they may get a better answer, I encourage it!